# JS: Switch statement default versus having the default outside of the switch?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

if there is a switch statement that has a `default`, would the same be achieved by just putting whatever is in the `default` under the switch statement?

1)

```
function test(foo) {
   switch(foo.num) {
      case "1": 
        return "hello"
      case "2":
        return "bye"
      default: 
        return "neither"
   }
}
```

2. 

```
function test(foo) {
   switch(foo.num) {
      case "1": 
        return "hello"
      case "2":
        return "bye"
   }
   return "neither"
}
```

do these both always operate the same way or is there something I am overlooking?

Comment: One case it will fail is when you have `break` statement in cases not return, so that case it is not same, in the case you mentioned in code it is same but imo you shouldn't be doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you're doing, they're the same, but only because you're returning. Switch is often used for other statements other than `return` though, eg:

```
function test(foo) {
   switch(foo.num) {
      case "1": 
        console.log('1');
        break;
      case "2":
        console.log('2');
        break;
      default: 
        console.log('nope');
   }
}
```

Above, it'll log exactly one value when the function is called. But if you do

```
function test(foo) {
   switch(foo.num) {
      case "1": 
        console.log('1');
        break;
      case "2":
        console.log('2');
        break;
   }
   console.log('nope');
}
```

it may log 1 or 2, but then it'll also log `nope` regardless - *because you aren't returning inside the switch*.

In the case that you just want to return a value depending on another value, consider using an object instead - it's a lot more concise (and easier to understand).

```
const returnValues = {
  1: 'hello',
  2: 'bye',
};
const test = foo => returnValues[foo] ?? 'neither';
```

Comment: `Above, it'll log exactly one value when the function is called` no it won't as you don't have break statements